# Delete an item from a dictionary generated by SeqIO.index

Tags: python, dictionary, bioinformatics, biopython, fastq

I am using Python 2.6.6 and I am trying to remove `fastq` reads in `file2` that overlap (i.e., are identical to) reads in `file1`. Here is code I am trying to implement:

```
ref_reads = SeqIO.index("file1.fastq", "fastq")
spk_reads = SeqIO.index("file2.fastq", "fastq")

for spk in spk_reads:
    if spk in ref_reads:
    del ref_reads[spk]
```

However, I get this error related to my use of `del`:

**AttributeError: _IndexedSeqFileDict instance has no attribute '__delitem__'**

Is it possible to delete an item using the present formulation? How can I delete an item from a dictionary generated using `SeqIO.index()`?

I also tried the following:

```
# import read data
ref_reads = SeqIO.index("main.fastq", "fastq")
spk_reads = SeqIO.index("over.fastq", "fastq")

# note that ref_reads.keys() doesn't return a list but a 'dictionary-       keyiterator', 
# so we turn it into a set to work with it
ref_keys = set(ref_reads.keys())  
spk_keys = set(spk_reads.keys())

# loop to remove overlap reads
for spk in spk_keys:
    if spk in ref_keys:
        del ref_keys[spk]

# output data
output_handle = open(fname_out, "w")
SeqIO.write(ref_reads[ref_keys], output_handle, "fastq")
output_handle.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

SeqIO.index() doesn't return a true dictionary, but [a dictionary like object, giving the SeqRecord objects as values](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/SeqIO/__init__.py#L766):

> Note that this pseudo dictionary will not support all the methods of a
>       true Python dictionary, for example values() is not defined since this
>       would require loading all of the records into memory at once.

This dictionary like object is an [`_IndexedSeqFileDict`](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/File.py#L276) instance. The docstring mentions:

> Note that this dictionary is essentially read only. You cannot
>       add or change values, pop values, nor clear the dictionary.

So, you will need to convert your fastq file to an in-memory Python dictionary using `SeqIO.parse()` and `SeqIO.to_dict()`:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

ref_reads = SeqIO.parse("file1.fastq", "fastq")
spk_reads = SeqIO.parse("file1.fastq", "fastq")

ref_reads_dict = SeqIO.to_dict(ref_reads)

for spk in spk_reads:
    if spk.id in ref_reads_dict:
        del ref_reads_dict[spk.id]
```

If your files are so large that working with `SeqIO.parse()` isn't feasible, then I would do something like this:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

ref_reads = SeqIO.index("file1.fastq", "fastq")
spk_reads = SeqIO.index("file2.fastq", "fastq")

# note that ref_reads.keys() doesn't return a list but a 'dictionary-keyiterator', 
# so we turn it into a set to work with it
ref_keys = set(ref_reads.keys())  
spk_keys = set(spk_reads.keys())

unique_ref_keys = ref_keys - spk_keys

# this step might take a long time if your files are large
unique_ref_reads = {key: ref_reads[key] for key in unique_ref_keys}
```

**Edit, answer to your comment:**

> how can I again solve the original problem of deleting items from SeqIO.index("file1.fastq", "fastq")?

Like I stated above, `SeqIO.index("file1.fastq", "fastq")` returns a read-only `_IndexedSeqFileDict` object. So you **can not**, by design, delete items from it.

The updated code below shows how you can create a new fastq file where the overlapping reads are removed.

If you really want a new `SeqIO.index()` object, then you can read this file in again with `SeqIO.index()`.

```
from Bio import SeqIO

ref_reads = SeqIO.index("file1.fastq", "fastq")
spk_reads = SeqIO.index("file2.fastq", "fastq")

ref_keys = set(ref_reads.keys())  
spk_keys = set(spk_reads.keys())

unique_ref_keys = ref_keys - spk_keys

# conserve memory by using a generator expression
unique_ref_records = (ref_reads[key] for key in unique_ref_keys)

# output new file with overlapping reads removed
with open(fname_out, "w") as output_handle:
    SeqIO.write(unique_ref_records , output_handle, "fastq")

# optionally, create a new SeqIO.index() object 
unique_ref_reads = SeqIO.index(fname_out, "fastq")
```

Comment: Thnk you for the helpful advice. The first solution worked, but was slow compared to the code I am trying to improve upon. Could you please provide additional information concerning your second code block? I am trying to remove reads from file1.fastq that are also in file2.fastq. Based on your second solution, how can I again solve the original problem of deleting items from SeqIO.index("file1.fastq", "fastq")? I updated the question to reflect my latest attempt.